# How to use the transparency of the image used in a texture

Tags: modeling, uv, transparency

While following along I was able to use UV mapping for the eyes but once it came to the eyebrows something seems wrong. The example shows eyebrows that look like hair because they have transparency to them. When I mapped the eyebrows, I can see the texture on them but it seems almost as if there's something wrong with the transparency because it's as if they have a black background.

I've watched many many videos about UV mapping and they all seem to show the way that I am doing it and I've retried with a new project and it does the same thing no matter what I do.

[image: UV mapping]

[image: Result]

If you would like to see the project I have uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qOJI7o9q1W1HOTnEInrbbkJfRjgWF8id

I appreciate any suggestions or help.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify. UV are the coordinates used to map a texture. There is no transparency involved in UVs. Seems to me you are asking why the image used as texture is not transparent. You are not using the alpha channel of the image as alpha for the material I guess (I don't download files, sorry) Read: [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into what you are saying. I appreciate it!